# Oracle convert RAW to date format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I have a RAW field in my Oracle database that represents the date of user registered in system.

The value is something like `24E2321A0000000000` However I need convert the value to the date it represents (etc 2008-12-25 15:04:31).

I tried with `totimestamp` (see [this sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de8d5/2)) but that didn't work.

Comment: First try to convert this number into decimal and then you will be able to convert it into date..

Comment: How you are inserting this date into sql?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit：It's a legacy system, I don't know why they insert date to RAW feild, for bettter performance ?

Comment: @Rony: thanks for you quick reply. I tried to convert this "24E2321A0000000000" to number but failed.

Comment: @user2420342 put your code how your are inserting this date to system

Comment: @dholakiyaankit：I don't have the code, that's why I try to find a way  decode the date from RAW feild.

Comment: Legacy system how will you identify this date format?

Comment: how u tried to covert it into decimal just put your code

Comment: If it's a proprietary format we can't guess what it is any better than you. Do you have a reason think the value you've shown is the date in 2008? Why do you think it's a date at all if it isn't documented? Do you have source code that inserts records from a UI, which shows how it gets that value? I can't think of any reason to store a date as anything other than a DATE, particularly something so obscure - certainly not for performance. Although I wonder if this used to be in a different RDBMS and when it was moved they copied the internal representation from the old DB as RAW to 'save time'.

Comment: Please, provide more examples of real data. Can you register new user? With knowledge of actual time new user was registered and having respective raw value for him there are better chances to guess data storage format.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_binary_integer('24E2321A0000000000') raw_to_int
FROM dual
/
```

Output is 36. I'm not sure if you need days or hours. Next example is about adding 36 hours to SYSDATE:

```
-- SYSDATE + 36/24 --
SELECT SYSDATE+(utl_raw.cast_to_binary_integer('24E2321A0000000000')/24) my_date
FROM dual
/

MY_DATE
---------------------
12/13/2013 4:29:22 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

please try one

```
declare
d date;
begin
   dbms_stats.convert_raw_value (hextoraw('7876070A010101'), d);
   dbms_output.put_line (d);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

or even shorter, using the corresponding function:

```
select to_char (dbms_stats.CONVERT_RAW_TO_DATE (hextoraw ('7876070A010101')), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as raw_converted from dual;
```

result then:

```
RAW_CONVERTED
-------------------
2018-07-10 00:00:00
```